# Debian 8 (Jessie): Unable to connect to WIFI after update

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, iwlwifi

I recently updated my Debian 8 OS. Ever since, I've been unable to connect to wifi. LAN works just OK. See below a sample of my command output:

```
frank@debian8:~$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.


frank@debian8:~$ sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.


frank@debian8:~$ sudo ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:e6:d7:1e:50:21  
          inet addr:10.68.77.173  Bcast:10.68.77.255  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fe80::36e6:d7ff:fe1e:5021/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9246 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9323 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7078862 (6.7 MiB)  TX bytes:2001113 (1.9 MiB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7400000-f7420000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:925 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:925 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:104194 (101.7 KiB)  TX bytes:104194 (101.7 KiB)

frank@debian8:~$ lspci -vnn | grep -i net
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM [8086:155a] (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 73)


frank@debian8:~$ sudo dmesg|grep 'firmw\|wl'
[    4.588961] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode (-2)
[    4.589058] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode failed with error -2


frank@debian8:~$ sudo rfkill unblock all ; sudo ip link set wlan0 up
Cannot find device "wlan0"


frank@debian8:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4470]
03:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] [10de:1140] (rev a1)


frank@debian8:~$ sudo rfkill list
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I am using a DELL Latitude E5440.

**UPDATE:**

More command output:

```
frank@debian8:~$ lsmod | grep dell
dell_laptop            20480  0 
dell_smbios            16384  1 dell_laptop
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_smbios
dell_smm_hwmon         16384  0 
video                  40960  3 dell_laptop,nouveau,i915
dell_smo8800           16384  0 
dell_rbtn              16384  1 
rfkill                 24576  5 bluetooth,dell_laptop,dell_rbtn,cfg80211
```

Comment: @GAD3R: After running `sudo ip link set wlan0 up`, I get the following error: `Cannot find device "wlan0"`

Comment: what is the output of `lspci -knn | grep net -A2` ?  and `rfkill list` ? please [edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/395161/edit)

Comment: Bring up the interface after unblocking it. `rfkill unblock all` ; `ip link set wlan0 up`

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [**Intel**](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) , the `Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260` should work on kernel version 4.1 and higher.

Add `backports` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

save and install a new kernel from backports:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.3-amd64
sudo reboot
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

The missing dependencies should be installed through `apt-get install -t jessie-backports package-name`.

Comment: Running `sudo ip link  set wlan0 up` gives me `Cannot find device "wlan0"`.

Answer (score 2):

Installing the firmware from the backports and running these command's did it for me.

```
apt-get install -t jessie-backports firmware-iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi
rfkill unblock all
```

Upon reboot, I was able to use `wlan0`.